# Let $O$ be an open subset of $X=\prod\limits_{n\in\omega}X_n$, then $O=p_F^{-1}p_F(O)$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $O$ be an open subset in $X=\prod\limits_{n\in\omega}X_n$, then $O=p_F^{-1}p_F(O)$ for some finite set $F\subset\omega$.

Where $p_F$ is the projection of $X$ onto $X_F=\prod\limits_{n\in F}X_n$.

How can we prove this claim? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean *for any* finite $F$?

Comment: @Ilya, no. Please see [Topological Groups and Related Structures](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hIEnzrOBbW0C&pg=PA358&lpg=PA358&dq=every%20compact%20space%20is%20a%20continuous%20image%20of%20a%20moscow%20space&source=bl&ots=fVNdS65_ud&sig=Fm0RqNKUht0Eh_vGx58MzVLtgz4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=75JJUcerKuiU0QXw1YDoDg&sqi=2&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=every%20compact%20space%20is%20a%20continuous%20image%20of%20a%20moscow%20space&f=false) p356, Lemma 6.3.6.

Comment: that part of the proof takes a _standard_ open neighbourhood of a point in $X$, and these sets will have this property.  (These would be sets in the standard basis for the product topology.)

Comment: I searched Google for this term, but did not obtain anything. What does "standard basis for the product topology" mean?

Comment: This is one of those times where you use context to figure out what is meant.  Clearly taking any arbitrary open neighbourhood will not work, but there is a natural neighbourhood base that will work.

Comment: i.e. for any open nbhood $U$ of $y$ in $X$, there exist an open nbhood $O$ of $y$ contained in $U$ and $O=p_F^{-1}p_F(O)$ for some finite $F\subset \omega$ ?

Comment: Yes.  Recall that the standard basis for the product topology would be the family of all sets of the form $\prod_{n \in \omega} U_n$ where $U_n \subseteq X_n$ is open, and $U_n = X_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.  If $O$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ then there is such a set $U = \prod_{n \in \omega} U_n$ with $y \in U \subseteq O$.  Letting $F = \{ n \in \omega : U_n \neq X_n \}$ it follows that $F$ is finite and $U = p_F^{-1} p_F ( U )$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a very hard time proving this claim.  Let $X_n = \mathbb{R}$ for all $n < \omega$, and define an open $U \subseteq X = \prod_{n \in \omega} X_n = \mathbb{R}^\omega$ by $$U = \{ x = ( x_n )_{n \in \omega} \in \mathbb{R}^\omega : ( \exists n \in \omega ) ( 0 < x_n < 1 ) \}.$$  For any finite $F \subseteq \omega$ we have that $p_F [ U ] = \mathbb{R}^F$, meaning that $p_F^{-1} p_F [ U ] = \mathbb{R}^\omega$.

Comment: Or just let $U=\Bbb R^\omega\setminus\{\langle 0,0,0,\dots\rangle\}$.

Comment: @Brian: Sure, if you want to use an _easy_ example.... :-)

Comment: Isn’t laziness one hallmark of a good mathematician? :-)